# CPT - Nice url with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I read lot of topick, but it don't work. And I really don't know what i do wrong ...

I put this code the the function.php of my child theme :

```
function capitaine_rewrite_url() {
    
    add_rewrite_tag( '%payment%','([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%meals%','([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%property-type%' ,'([^&]+)' );
    
    add_rewrite_rule(
      'properties/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)',
      'index.php?post_type=properties&payment=$matches[1]&meals=$matches[2]&property-type=$matches[3]',
      'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'capitaine_rewrite_url' );
```

I don't dorget to update /wp-admin/options-permalink.php"

Nothink change ...

With "Monkeman we can see "my" code go first before the standard
[image]

any idea what I'm forgetting?

thnaks for your help !

Comment: Have you tested that your URL matches with monkeyman rewrite analyser or a similar tool? Just because you added a rule doesn't mean the URL matches, and even if it is a match, that doesn't mean it was used. WP uses the first matching rule, if your rule is second then it isn't used.

Comment: Also, are you sure your file is named `fonction.php`? It should be `functions.php`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer ! it's "function" yes, i write wronk before sorry. I instal MONKEYMAN and i can see "my" fonction first for properties/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+). Just after i can see the standard "properties/?$", but it's alway the second who work